# How to find missing ppp commands?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, embedded, buildroot, ppp

I made my own linux distribution with buildroot. In "make menuconfig" and "make linux-menuconfig" I checked all options related to "ppp" and "pppd". Unfortunately, after building my distribution I can't use the commands "pon", "poff", "plog" and probably others. The system cannot see them. I looked and they are not in "/ usr / bin" or "/ usr / sbin". What could be causing this? I found out somewhere that these are debian-only commands, but how can I enable the pppd daemon?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ppd`, `pppd`, `pon`, and etc  are userland applications you need to install them using buildroot. So far you have enabled support in the kernel for `ppp` but you have not installed the actual application that manages the `ppp` connections which is `pppd`

If build root doesn't already have a package for `ppp`/`pppd`, you can make a recipe to do that. The official website is: https://ppp.samba.org/

`pon`, `poff`, and `plog` can be found in the [scripts](https://github.com/ppp-project/ppp/tree/master/scripts) directory of the sources code.

Comment: I checked all the "ppp" and "pppd" options in "make menuconfig" and "make linux-makeconfig", but unfortunately I couldn't find anything related to "pon". Could you please provide a path to these options?